# Gnuplot point interval from point plot

Tags: gnuplot

I know that I can control point interval by "pointinterval" or "pi" command. However, this command only works with "linespoint" or "lp" plotting style.

Can I manage point interval with "points" or "p" plotting style?

For example:

```
plot data u 1:2 w p pt 7 ps 1 pi 2000 lc rgb "red" title "density"
```

Here, I tried "pi 2000" for point interval with points plotting style but it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the points plotting style, you can control which data points to plot in regular intervals with the 'every' keyword. It goes right after the data file name. If you really wanted to only plot every 2000 data points:

```
plot "dataFile" every 2000 u 1:2 w p pt 7 ps 1 lc rgb "red" title "density"
```

"every" is quite sophisticated. Type 'help every' at a gnuplot prompt and you can get more details.

Comment: Note an important difference. With linespoint and pointinterval, the line is drawn through every point and the interval controls the points. With ‘every’, data points are skipped. If your interval is large, you may miss important detail in your plot.